# How can I create this environment

Tags: errors, environments, tcolorbox, theorems

I really want to have my environment to look like this:

[image]

Also, I saw these environments from the book `linear algebra done right`, which @Jinwen informed me about. I was wondering how would I create environments like these ones here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Anway, any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: `borderline west` is provided in tcolorbox library `skins`, so perhaps you didn't load it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is something for you to get start with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newtheoremstyle{basic}
    {0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
    {}{\;}{0.25em}
    {{\sffamily\bfseries\color{blue!50!cyan}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
        \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\theoremstyle{basic}

\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}

\tcolorboxenvironment{conclusion}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=blue!50!cyan!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{blue!50!cyan}, arc=.5mm
}

\begin{conclusion}
    \blindtext
\end{conclusion}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDED**:

Here is a brief example to demonstrated the idea that the color of the proof environments changes with the previous theorem-like environment. Note that the current approach won't work for proofs like `Proof of Theorem 3.1`, as it reads only the color of the previous environment. For this to work in the general case, some effort shall be needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
    {0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
    {}{\;}{0.25em}
    {{\sffamily\bfseries\color{theoremcolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
        \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
    {0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
    {}{\;}{0.25em}
    {{\sffamily\bfseries\color{definitioncolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
        \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\theoremstyle{theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\colorlet{theoremcolor}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{definitioncolor}{red!50!orange}

\definecolor{proofcolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theoremcolor!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theoremcolor}, arc=.5mm
}

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=definitioncolor!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{definitioncolor}, arc=.5mm
}

% These patches must be placed after \tcolorboxenvironment !
\AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theoremcolor}}
\AddToHook{env/definition/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{definitioncolor}}

\renewcommand{\proofname}{%
    \normalfont\sffamily\bfseries%
    \color{proofcolor}Proof%
}
\let\qedsymbolMyOriginal\qedsymbol
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{%
    \color{proofcolor}\qedsymbolMyOriginal%
}


\begin{theorem}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    Some text.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}
    \blindtext
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}
    Some text.
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And if one wants to put the proofs in color boxes too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
    {0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
    {}{\;}{0.25em}
    {{\sffamily\bfseries\color{theoremcolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
        \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
    {0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
    {}{\;}{0.25em}
    {{\sffamily\bfseries\color{definitioncolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
        \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\theoremstyle{theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\colorlet{theoremcolor}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{definitioncolor}{red!50!orange}

\definecolor{proofcolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theoremcolor!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theoremcolor}, arc=.5mm
}

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=definitioncolor!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{definitioncolor}, arc=.5mm
}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    opacityback=0, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{proofcolor}, arc=.5mm
}

% These patches must be placed after \tcolorboxenvironment !
\AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theoremcolor}}
\AddToHook{env/definition/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{definitioncolor}}

\renewcommand{\proofname}{%
    \normalfont\sffamily\bfseries%
    \color{proofcolor}Proof%
}
\let\qedsymbolMyOriginal\qedsymbol
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{%
    \color{proofcolor}\qedsymbolMyOriginal%
}


\begin{theorem}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    Some text.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}
    \blindtext
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}
    Some text.
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This finally workd!!!!!

Comment: @SingularisArt As @muzimuzhi pointed out in his comment, the key `borderline west` requires the library `skins`. Here I simply use the option `many` to make `tcolorbox` load frequently used modules. Did you check if the corresponding tcolorbox library has been loaded? (You can also load it explicitly via `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`.)

Comment: Yeah. After I added `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`, it finally worked. Also, quick question, how can I make the `proof` environment change color based on what environment it's near? For example, if it's near the `conclusion` environment, then the `proof` environment will be blue. But if it's near the `definition` environment, then it will be green. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @SingularisArt This is definitely possible and not very hard. The thing is that I believe putting `proof` environments inside color boxes does not make you document clearer, so I propose that you just change the color of the title `Proof`. If you are interested in that, I can expand my answer to include such an approach ;)

Comment: Yes. If you can, that will be amazing.

Comment: @SingularisArt In case you are interested, try my document class `lebhart` which is available on CTAN. I think your idea that proof color changes with the environment is cool. Recently I've been rewriting all my packages and classes with `expl3`, so maybe I can introduce this feature in the next major update.

Comment: I'll definitely check that out!

Comment: @SingularisArt I've added an example, see if this what you wished for :)

Comment: That's what I wanted! But, how would make the line of the left the same color os the previous line just like you did with the title?

Comment: @SingularisArt That is exactly how you did it for `theorem`: the `\tcolorboxenvironment`. The color `proofcolor` can be used to specify its color. However, just as a personal note, I don't think put a line near everything looks very beautiful in a document, this kind of make the document feels broken into pieces. If you insist on this design, some effort needs to be made to choose the best-looking style (color, frame, etc.) to make your document feel consistent and clear.

Comment: I'll keep that into consideration. Thank you SO MUCH for your help!! :-)

Comment: @SingularisArt When making my own style, I compared quite a lot different designs, and the simplest and clearest I'd seen is that used in the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" -- maybe you can take a look at its design. If you want to make your document look "modern" by using color boxes, here are three tips: 1) try to use no more than 5 colors; 2) make the styles of different types of theorem-like environments vary (yet in a consistent way) so that one can see clearly what type an environment is at glance; 3) typeset a long math note and share with your friends to check if it is clear enough.

Comment: You're right. The pdf for "Linear Algebra Done Right" looks absolutely beautiful. How could I make my environments look like that?

Comment: @SingularisArt That is easy. For the colorbox, you can see the documentation of `tcolorbox` or see what I did in `colorist.sty` (I apologize that the current version looks messy -- search for `\tcolorboxenvironment` of the `example` environment, for example). For the theorem style, see the documentation of `amsthm` and various examples over this site. But before you start, think clearly if this is really what you wanted: the key to the clear design of LADR is that every statement has its one-line summary, which is not the case for every document (yet is also what makes LADR remarkable).

Comment: I tried to do what you did with the `proof`, but make the line change color, but I cannot get it to work. [Here's](https://github.com/SingularisArt/notes/blob/master/Grade-10/semester-1/preamble.tex#L270-L395) the link to my preamble.

Comment: @SingularisArt I just added another example to the answer, hopefully this shall be helpful. I must say that you have a remarkable organization of your notes, congratulations and keep working!

Comment: Thank you! I finally got everything that I need! God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final result. Thanks a ton to @Jinwen.

Here's the final code:

```tex
\documentclass{tuftebook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\makeatletter

\def\renewtheorem#1{%
    \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
    \gdef\renewtheorem@envname{#1}
    \renewtheorem@secpar
}
\def\renewtheorem@secpar{\@ifnextchar[{\renewtheorem@numberedlike}{\renewtheorem@nonumberedlike}}
\def\renewtheorem@numberedlike[#1]#2{\newtheorem{\renewtheorem@envname}[#1]{#2}}
\def\renewtheorem@nonumberedlike#1{
    \def\renewtheorem@caption{#1}
    \edef\renewtheorem@nowithin{\noexpand\newtheorem{\renewtheorem@envname}{\renewtheorem@caption}}
    \renewtheorem@thirdpar
}
\def\renewtheorem@thirdpar{\@ifnextchar[{\renewtheorem@within}{\renewtheorem@nowithin}}
\def\renewtheorem@within[#1]{\renewtheorem@nowithin[#1]}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% New environments %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatother
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

% Color definitions

\definecolor{proofcolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

% Dark orange and Dark Red rgb
\definecolor{theorembordercolor}{RGB}{151, 63, 5}
\definecolor{theorembackgroundcolor}{RGB}{248, 241, 234}

\definecolor{examplebordercolor}{RGB}{0, 110, 184}
\definecolor{examplebackgroundcolor}{RGB}{240, 244, 250}

\definecolor{definitionbordercolor}{RGB}{0, 150, 85}
\definecolor{definitionbackgroundcolor}{RGB}{239, 247, 243}

\definecolor{propertybordercolor}{RGB}{128, 0, 128}
\definecolor{propertybackgroundcolor}{RGB}{255, 240, 255}

\definecolor{formulabordercolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{formulabackgroundcolor}{RGB}{230, 229, 245}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{theorembordercolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
\thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{definitionbordercolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
\thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{example}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{examplebordercolor}\thmname{#1}.}
\thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{property}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{propertybordercolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
\thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

\newtheoremstyle{formula}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{formulabordercolor}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{\textup{#2}}.}
\thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(#3)}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Theorem Environments %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{postulate}{Postulate}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{postulate}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{conjecture}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{corollary}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{conclusion}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=theorembackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{theorembordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition Environments %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{review}{Review}

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=definitionbackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{definitionbordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{review}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=definitionbackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{definitionbordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example Environments %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\tcolorboxenvironment{example}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=examplebackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{examplebordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{remark}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=white, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{examplebordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=white, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{examplebordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Property Environments %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{property}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\tcolorboxenvironment{property}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=propertybackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{propertybordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}
\tcolorboxenvironment{proposition}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=propertybackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{propertybordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formula %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{formula}
\newtheorem{formula}{Formula}

\tcolorboxenvironment{formula}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=formulabackgroundcolor, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{formulabordercolor}, arc=.5mm
}

%%%%%%%%%
% Proof %
%%%%%%%%%

% These patches must be placed after \tcolorboxenvironment !
\AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/postulate/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/conjecture/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/corollary/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/lemma/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/conclusion/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{theorembordercolor}}

\AddToHook{env/definition/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{definitionbordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/review/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{definitionbordercolor}}

\AddToHook{env/example/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{examplebordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/remark/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{examplebordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/note/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{examplebordercolor}}

\AddToHook{env/property/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{propertybordercolor}}
\AddToHook{env/proposition/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{propertybordercolor}}

\AddToHook{env/formula/after}{\colorlet{proofcolor}{formulabordercolor}}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{Q.E.D.}
\let\qedsymbolMyOriginal\qedsymbol
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{
    \color{proofcolor}\qedsymbolMyOriginal
}

\newtheoremstyle{proof}
{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}
{}{\;}{0.25em}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\color{proofcolor}\thmname{#1}.}
    \thmnote{\normalfont\color{black}~(\textit{#3})}}

\theoremstyle{proof}
\renewtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{
    enhanced jigsaw, pad at break*=1mm, breakable,
    left=4mm, right=4mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    colback=white, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{0mm}{proofcolor}, arc=.5mm
}

\newenvironment{info}{\begin{tcolorbox}[
            arc=0mm,
            colback=white,
            colframe=gray,
            title=Info,
            fonttitle=\sffamily,
            breakable
        ]}{\end{tcolorbox}}
\newenvironment{terminology}{\begin{tcolorbox}[
            arc=0mm,
            colback=white,
            colframe=green!60!black,
            title=Terminology,
            fonttitle=\sffamily,
            breakable
        ]}{\end{tcolorbox}}
\newenvironment{warning}{\begin{tcolorbox}[
            arc=0mm,
            colback=white,
            colframe=red,
            title=Warning,
            fonttitle=\sffamily,
            breakable
        ]}{\end{tcolorbox}}
\newenvironment{caution}{\begin{tcolorbox}[
            arc=0mm,
            colback=white,
            colframe=yellow,
            title=Caution,
            fonttitle=\sffamily,
            breakable
        ]}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
  \mbox{}\newpage

  \begin{theorem}[Theorem 1]
    \label{thrm:theorem_1}

    \lipsum[1]
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{postulate}[Postulate 1]
    \label{post:postulate_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{postulate}

  \begin{conjecture}[Conjecture 1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{conjecture}

  \begin{corollary}
    \label{corl:corollary_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{corollary}

  \begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:lemma_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{lemma}

  \begin{conclusion}
    \label{conc:conclusion_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{conclusion}

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{definition}[Definition 1]
    \label{def:definition_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{definition}

  \begin{review}[Review 1]
    \label{rev:review_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{review}

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_2}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_4}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{example}
    \label{exm:example_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{example}

  \begin{remark}[Remark 1]
    \label{rmk:remark_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{remark}

  \begin{note}
    \label{nte:note_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{note}

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_3}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{property}[Property 1]
    \label{prop:property_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{property}

  \begin{proposition}[Proposition 1]
    \label{prop:proposition_1}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proposition}

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_4}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{formula}[Formula 1]
    \label{form:formula_1}

    \lipsum[1]
  \end{formula}

  \begin{proof}
    \label{prf:proof_5}
  
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{proof}

  \newpage

  \begin{info}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{info}

  \begin{terminology}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{terminology}

  \begin{warning}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{warning}

  \begin{caution}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{caution}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the tuftebook.cls file:

```
\LoadClass[20pt,a4paper,11pt,openany,tikz]{report}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesFile{tuftebook.cls}[2020/03/24 v1.00a Caesar book]

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{sidenotes}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, skip=2pt}
\RequirePackage[maxfloats=45]{morefloats}

\RequirePackage{marginfix}
\newcommand{\caesar@letterspace}[1]{#1}
\RequirePackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
\@ifpackagelater{microtype}{2011/08/18}
{\renewcommand{\caesar@letterspace}[1]{\textls{#1}}}
{\AtEndDocument{\ClassWarningNoLine{caesar_book}{Need newest microtype for letterspacing.}}}

% Setting up the dimensions of the page using the package geometry.
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=297mm,
    left=42pt,
    top=72pt,
    textwidth=320pt,
    marginparsep=20pt,
    marginparwidth=180pt,
    textheight=650pt,
    footskip=40pt,
}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{13pt}\selectfont}%
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}%

\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}
    {\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}
        {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\overhang}}
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}}
    }
    {\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}
        {\end{adjustwidth*}}
        {\end{adjustwidth}}
    }

\RequirePackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\RequirePackage{fmtcount}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large\sf}
{\filleft
\textls{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}} \expandafter\textls\expandafter{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}}
{1.5ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace*{1.1ex}
\filright}
[\vspace*{1.5ex}
\titlerule]


% This is used for chapters
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}                       % Helper package
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}          % Line at the header invisible
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}          % Line at the footer visible
}

% Basic formatting.
% \renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\pagestyle{empty}}
% \renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{fancy}}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\marginparstyle}{\footnotesize}
\long\def\@ympar#1{
    \@savemarbox\@marbox{\marginparstyle#1}
    \global\setbox\@currbox\copy\@marbox
    \@xympar}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\marginparstyle}

% Setting up itemize and enumerate.
\RequirePackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\newcommand\newthought[1]{
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \sidecite { o o m }
{ 
    \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}
        {
          \sidenote{\fullcite{#3}}
        }
        {
          \sidenote{\fullcite[#2]{#3}}
        }
    }
    {
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}
        {
          \sidenote{\fullcite[#1]{#3}}
        }
        {
          \sidenote{\fullcite[#1][#2]{#3}}
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage[margincaption,outercaption,,wide]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t} 
\captionsetup{labelfont={sf,bf,footnotesize}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}[]{labelfont={sf,bf,footnotesize}, font=footnotesize, justification=justified}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}[]{labelfont={sf,bf,footnotesize}, font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}[]{labelfont={sf,bf,footnotesize}, font=footnotesize}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{13pt}\selectfont}%
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}%
```